# How to update image in HTML with image from database dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I would like to update my  element on my HTML page with an image stored in a mysql database through javascript but i have no idea how to ensure that the image i upload is going to be saved in html and appear everytime i load it. how would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more how you want to load it ?
Don't get at the Moment what you want to do.
But I guess you should Google Ajax.

EDIT!! 
I think I understand now what you want.
You can Upload your Image with PHP and a Form.
Store the image in your Folder on Website Root.
Insert the image Path to your DB.

Then you can go and when your Event is triggered you perform a Ajax Request to a File like getImage.php 
This one select the Image Path from Database and return it or return the whole image with already img Tag.

If Questions just ask or add me in Skype under varex.media
Sy

Comment: This solution actually sounds like what i want to do. im going to try this approach and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @skandal No Problem :) let me know when you need more help or something dont work

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to set the src property: `imageObject.src = URL` . Example:  `document.getElementById("id").src = "image.png";`
FOR details: check [Image src Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp)